# I want to install the springsource-tool-suite to existing exclipse, after installing I can not find the spring options in window > Preferences

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have install the springsource-tool-suite-3.7.3.RELEASE-e4.5.2-updatesite.zip to the eclipse by "Install new software", however I cannot find the spring option at the "window > preference" and the plugin does not work.

Comment: my eclipse version is 4.5.2

Comment: Please add more details and be more specific. What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Check Help -> Installation Details. There must be tab for Installation Details checks if there are any Spring plugins. Also checks Plugins and Features tabds. See if you have any errors like "Failed to resolve bundle" etc. in the error log on the startup.